# Django: display float number

Tags: django

In my models file (django) I have a following code

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return  u'EXAM: grade: %f' % (self.get_grade_display())
```

and in admin panel I have obrained

```
EXAM: grade: 2.000000
```

Anyone knows how to truncate the float number to the following format:

```
EXAM: grade: 2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have already found: `%.1f`

and code:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return  u'EXAM: grade: %.1f' % (self.get_grade_display())
```

Comment: You can also do this `round(self.get_grade_display(), 1)`